# Present Modal View Controller On Top of UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, modalviewcontroller

I have my app that is below a UINavigationController and therefore below a UINavigationBar. I want to present a Modal View Controller on top of this UINavigationBar because the controller I wrote doesn't make sense if it's below it (that is, I want to hide the navigation bar when showing this view controller).

Presenting it with this code:

```
    ukc = [[UnlockKeyboardViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentModalViewController:ukc animated:NO];
```

Cause the Modal view controller to be below the UINavigationBar. That UINavigationBar shouldn't show up when I show this modal view. How can I go around that?

PS: This is a jailbreak app, so there's no Interface Builder.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:ukc animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Extra info upon working with a related issue:

note173's answer works with `animated:YES` too. The user will see `ukc`'s view slide up over the nav stack.

And if you subsequently need to dismiss `ukc` and return to `self`'s view, do this:

```
        [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

The first call dismisses `ukc`. The second call dismisses the nav controller. What the user sees is `ukc`'s view sliding down to reveal `self`'s view, with a glimpse of the navigation stack behind it.

So what you have here is a way of switching directly from the nav stack to some other regular view controller, and then back to a base view controller, all with animations that make sequential sense.

(If your aim was to switch back and forth between the nav stack and `ukc`, you would dismiss `ukc` with one call -- `self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` which would slide `ukc`'s view down to reveal the nav stack.)

Note that these methods are deprecated in iOS 5. I assume `presentViewController` and `dismissViewControllerAnimated` would do the same thing, but I haven't tested them.

Comment: Yes, presentViewController and dismissViewControllerAnimated are the correct methods to use at the moment.