# When calling a function to switch to another ViewController, the application crashes

Tags: ios, swift

Error text:

> Application tried to present modally an active controller.

Moreover, all elements seem to be called for the first time. The application crashes most likely due to the navigation controller. How can I fix this error?

```
@objc private func taskButtonTouched(){
    let vc = TaskVC()
    let navigationController = OptionalNC(rootViewController: vc)
    navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil) 
}
```

Comment: why are you presenting `vc` why now `navigationController` ?? shouldn't be `self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)` ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11658286/4475605

Comment: let vc = TaskVC()
    let navigationController = OptionalNC(rootViewController: vc)
    navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
let  objTaskVC = navigation.viewControllers.first as! TaskVC
    self.present(objTaskVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: @ Елисей Андросов- try this

Comment: @Bilal So the application does not crash, however, the view becomes empty. That is, the view to which this function refers is located text view, and if you add a navigation controller in this way the text view disappears

Comment: @DevendraAgnihotri Did not work

Comment: @Bilal I solved this problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must present OptionalNC insetead TaskVC

```
@objc private func taskButtonTouched(){
    let vc = TaskVC()
    let navigationController = OptionalNC(rootViewController: vc)
    navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```